# Create a condition to replace string in a column with strings from other column of different table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, join, replace

Not sure if I am framing this question right. I need some help with creating a select query in MS SQL Server, where I can replace strings in **Table A > Values** column with strings from a **Table B > Deliverables**.

The Table A > Values are specifically named as Deliverable 01, 02 and Table B > Deliverables are written something like D1: ABC, D2: DEF for some project IDs and Deliverable 1: ABC, Deliverable 2: DEF for other project ID

I am not looking for the obvious joins.

I am actually doing this for Crystal reports where I need to put some sort of condition where whenever there is a Deliverable 01 from Table A, replace it with **D1: ABC** or **Deliverable 1: ABC** based on the Project No.

I am guessing it might require some string manipulation, but how to do that?

For eg:

Table A

```
   Project ID      Value
    100            Deliverable 01
    100            Deliverable 02
    100            Deliverable 03
    100            Deliverable 04
    :
    :
    100            Deliverable 11 
-------------------------------------
    101            Deliverable 01
    101            Deliverable 02
    101            Deliverable 03       
    101            Deliverable 04
```

Table B

```
    Project ID      Deliverables
    100            D1: ABC
    100            D2: DEF
    100            D3: GHI
    100            D4: PQR
    :
    100            D11:XYZ 
-------------------------------------
    101            Deliverable 1: ABC
    101            Deliverable 2: DEF
    101            Deliverable 3: GHI       
    101            Deliverable 4: PQR
    101            Deliverable10: XYZ
```

Comment: What are the expected results? And what code do you have so far?

Comment: I am actually doing this for Crystal reports where I need to put some sort of condition where whenever there is a Deliverable 01 from Table A, replace it with D1: ABC or Deliverable 1: ABC based on the Project No.

Comment: I find your question unclear without desired results.  I suspect it has to do with string matching but it is not clear.  And there are no other columns, so it just begs the question of why you don't use Table B.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CASE` in SQL Server.

For example:

```
CASE WHEN ProjectNo  = THEN 'Deliverable 1 : ABC' END
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of records doesn't make cross-join performance unacceptable, you can add both tables to the report without a join.
Then add a ***record selection condition*** such as:

```
Replace(Split({B.Deliverables}, ": ")[1] = "D" + ToText(Cdbl(Split({A.Value}, " ")[2]),0);
```

Or use a SQL Server ***VIEW*** with the same logic (that would yield the best performance).

Or a Crystal ***Command*** with that logic in the ON condition for the join.

Or a Crystal ***SQL Expression*** with a correlated query with the same logic.

Or a ***linked subreport*** with the same logic.